How to interpret molecular orbital (HOMO - LUMO) plots in Chem3D 22.0?
Recently, I have been trying to understand the origin of the difference in reactivity of alkynyl-boron(ate) complexes so I tried to generate a molecular orbital plot on Chem3D (Version 22.0.22 64bit) of two such molecules: phenyl-hexynyl ''ate'' complex and hexyl -hexynyl ''ate'' complex (images are provided below respectively)
 
After minimizing the energy of the structure and computing properties in Chem3D itself, I generated a ''molecular orbital surface'' plot.
This is the generated HOMO molecular orbital plot of the phenyl-hexynyl ''ate'' complex
 on Chem3D. The value of HOMO and LUMO are -11.24 eV and 0.3 eV
And this is the generated HOMO molecular orbital plot of hexyl-hexynyl ''ate'' complex
on Chem3D.  The value of HOMO and LUMO are -10.214 eV and +4.201 eV
With all these informations in hand, is it possible to predict which molecule has more tendency for electrophilic addition?
Also, is it possible to claim which carbon atom of those molecules have the tendency to undergo electrophilic addition based on the lobes of HOMO of the molecule?

